# lubridate: tomorrow at specific time?

Tags: r, lubridate

I need to create a POSIXt object representing *tomorrow at 6 AM* (local time).
The best `lubridate` expression I've come up with is this:

```
lubridate::floor_date(lubridate::now() + lubridate::days(1), "day") + lubridate::hours(6))
```

This feels a bit clunky ("now + 1 day -> truncate to the nearest day -> + 6 hours").
Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working for me in my timezone (CET):

```
library(lubridate)
ceiling_date(now(), "day") + hours(6)
floor_date(now(), "day") + hours(30)
```

Both return

> ```
> [1] "2020-01-08 06:00:00 CET"
> ```

**EDIT**: This is working as well:

```
library(lubridate)
`tz<-`(today() + hours(30), "")
`tz<-`(Sys.Date() + hours(30), "")
```

Both return (in my local timezone)

> ```
> [1] "2020-01-08 06:00:00 CET"
> ```

(Explanation below)

#### Addendum

Interestingly, [Ronak Shah's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59621237/3817004) using `Sys.Date()` as well as [Brian's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59621210/lubridate-tomorrow-at-specific-time/59623592#comment105407085_59621237) to use `lubridate::today()` switch the time zone to UTC:

```
Sys.Date() + 1 + lubridate::hours(6)
```

> ```
> [1] "2020-01-08 06:00:00 UTC"
> ```

```
library(lubridate)
today() + hours(30)
```

> ```
> [1] "2020-01-08 06:00:00 UTC"
> ```

which is *not* in line with OP's requirement of *local time*.

Apparently, this sneeks in while coercing from `Date` to `POSIXct` class:

`lubridate::hours()` returns a `Period` object. When adding a `Period` object to a `Date` object it seems that `lubridate::as_datetime()` is being used for coersion. `as_datetime()` uses `"UTC"` as default timezone. The timezone can be set afterwards by, e.g.,

```
`tz<-`(today() + hours(30), "")
```

Comment: I didn't even realize `ceiling_date` was a function ... that works best, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could do

```
Sys.Date() + 1 + lubridate::hours(6)
#[1] "2020-01-08 06:00:00 UTC"
```

Comment: or `lubridate::today()` instead of `Sys.Date()`

Comment: Yeah that works, thanks! I think `lubridate::today()` is a bit safer than `Sys.Date()` just due to implicit timezone conversions when using some of the base R's datetime functions.

Comment: @mmuurr, Both `Sys.Date()` and `lubridate::today()` return an object of class `Date` which does not have a timezone attribute. Both are identical, i.e., `identical(Sys.Date(), lubridate::today())` is `TRUE`. The crucial point is the coersion from Date to DateTime class where timezones are important.